# ObjectDataSource -> Method taking two params one being Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am updating an old website to a more modern look.  They want the ability to `CRUD` their datatables so users can easily edit/update/delete things without going to special pages.

To do this I'm setting up an ObjectDataSource to their old methods.

Their methods take a param of Connection String

```
GetCustStaff(string cstGID, string ConnString);
```

How do I tell the ObjectDataSource that the ConnString value comes from the web.config?

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Connection").ToString()
```

The only options it gives me to fill the Param are `(None, Cookie, Control, Form, Profile, QueryString, Session, RouteData).`

Anyone have any idea how I can circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set it to "None", and add this to your object data source code (.ASPX):

```
 <SelectParameters>
           <asp:Parameter Name="connString" Type="String" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

and

```
onselecting="ObjectDataSource_Selecting"
```

complete code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" onselecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="connString" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

then, in your code behind:

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["connString"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Connection").ToString();

}
```

[useful link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581787.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class and call the methods from that. You'd add the ConnectionString with a variable/const in method in the class. It may be a better way to wrap the existing code. You may also need a selectcount method- but I'm not entirely sure what you want to bind the object data source to.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objStaff" runat="server" SelectCountMethod="GetStaffDataCount" SelectMethod="GetStaffData" TypeName="yourNameSpace.ClassName">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="StaffID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

new
then in your class

```
public class ClassName(){

protected void getStaffData(int staffID)
{
 GetCustStaff(staffID, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Connection").ToString())

...//fill method 

}
```

}